# longtable different last page

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a longtable with 4 columns. I can fit more on each page by making an 8 column table and having the columns repeat as shown in the example below. However, due to the odd number of values for R, the final page has only 4 columns of data. Is there a way in the longtable package to have the last page have a different number of columns from the rest of table, using multicolumn for example? I saw mention somewhere about an \endlasthead command, but it isn't in the longtable documentation, and isn't a recognized command. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

        \begin{landscape}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
        \begin{longtable}[c]{rlllrlll}
        \caption{Data \label{tab:data}} \\
        \toprule
        \( R \)& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} & \( R \) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:data} continued} \\
        \midrule
        \( R \)& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} & \( R \) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        
        0.5        & 0.03926622(12)  &   0.6872(5)   &   0.03886(2)   & 5.0        & 0.03926622(14)  &   0.48923(9)  &   0.027441(3)   \\*
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   &            & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\*
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   &            & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\*
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   &            & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\*
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   &            & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\*
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  &            & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\*
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  &            & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   &            & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\*
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   &            & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\*
              & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   &            & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\\noalign{\penalty-5000}
        0.5        & 0.03926622(12)  &   0.6872(5)   &   0.03886(2)   & 5.0        & 0.03926622(14)  &   0.48923(9)  &   0.027441(3)   \\*
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   &            & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\*
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   &            & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\*
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   &            & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\*
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   &            & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\*
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  &            & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\*
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  &            & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   &            & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\*
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   &            & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\*
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   &            & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\\noalign{\penalty-5000}
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   &            & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\*
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  &            & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\*
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  &            & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                                      & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   &            & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\*
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   &            & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\*
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   &            & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\*
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   &            & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\*
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  &            & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\*
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  &            & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
    3.0        & 0.0392662(4)    &   0.5040(3)   &   0.028289(9)  & & & & \\*
               & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4676(2)   &   0.05920(2)   & & & & \\*
               & 0.157087(2)     &   0.4000(6)   &   0.13014(7)   & & & & \\*
               & 0.2356338(10)   &   0.3397(2)   &   0.21639(12)  & & & & \\*
               & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2851(3)   &   0.32284(15)  & & & & \\*
               & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2359(6)   &   0.4571(3)    & & & & \\*
               & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2134(5)   &   0.5380(3)    & & & & \\*
               & 0.471270(3)     &   0.1919(9)   &   0.6305(4)    & & & & \\*
               & 0.5105275(14)   &   0.1714(5)   &   0.7372(6)    & & & & \\*
               & 0.549809(2)     &   0.1519(8)   &   0.8613(8)    & & & & \\*
               & 0.573261(3)     &   0.141(2)    &   0.9458(10)   & & & & \\*
               & 0.589086(2)     &   0.1346(7)   &   1.0080(12)   & & & & \\*
               & 0.604932(4)     &   0.129(2)    &   1.0754(13)   & & & & \\*
    \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It occurred to me that you have to manually determine how much data will fit on a page in order to change formats between 8 and 4 columns.  You could just use multiple tabulars, one for each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official answer is "no" and it's a bit tricky to implement a "last head" command as `longtable` really doesn't know it is nearing the end at the point it adds the heading.

But if it is for a specific document and you have no regard for the brilliantly structured internal coding of `longtable`  and want to smash straight through it, you could do

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

        \begin{landscape}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
        \begin{longtable}[c]{rlllrlll}
        \caption{Data \label{tab:data}} \\
        \toprule
        \( R \)& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} & \( R \) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:data} continued} \\
        \midrule
        \( R \)& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} & \( R \) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        
        0.5        & 0.03926622(12)  &   0.6872(5)   &   0.03886(2)   & 5.0        & 0.03926622(14)  &   0.48923(9)  &   0.027441(3)   \\*
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   &            & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\*
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   &            & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\*
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   &            & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\*
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   &            & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\*
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  &            & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\*
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  &            & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   &            & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\*
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   &            & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\*
              & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   &            & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\\noalign{\penalty-5000}
        0.5        & 0.03926622(12)  &   0.6872(5)   &   0.03886(2)   & 5.0        & 0.03926622(14)  &   0.48923(9)  &   0.027441(3)   \\*
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   &            & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\*
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   &            & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\*
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   &            & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\*
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   &            & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\*
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  &            & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\*
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  &            & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   &            & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\*
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   &            & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\*
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   &            & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\\noalign{\penalty-5000}
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   &            & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\*
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  &            & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\*
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  &            & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                                      & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   &            & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\*
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   &            & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\*
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   &            & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\*
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   &            & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\*
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  &            & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\*
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  &            & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
\noalign{\makeatletter\global\setbox9\box\LT@head}
\pagebreak
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:data} continued} \\*
        \midrule
        \( R \)& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} &  & & & \\*
        \midrule
        \\*
    3.0        & 0.0392662(4)    &   0.5040(3)   &   0.028289(9)  & & & & \\*
               & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4676(2)   &   0.05920(2)   & & & & \\*
               & 0.157087(2)     &   0.4000(6)   &   0.13014(7)   & & & & \\*
               & 0.2356338(10)   &   0.3397(2)   &   0.21639(12)  & & & & \\*
               & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2851(3)   &   0.32284(15)  & & & & \\*
               & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2359(6)   &   0.4571(3)    & & & & \\*
               & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2134(5)   &   0.5380(3)    & & & & \\*
               & 0.471270(3)     &   0.1919(9)   &   0.6305(4)    & & & & \\*
               & 0.5105275(14)   &   0.1714(5)   &   0.7372(6)    & & & & \\*
               & 0.549809(2)     &   0.1519(8)   &   0.8613(8)    & & & & \\*
               & 0.573261(3)     &   0.141(2)    &   0.9458(10)   & & & & \\*
               & 0.589086(2)     &   0.1346(7)   &   1.0080(12)   & & & & \\*
               & 0.604932(4)     &   0.129(2)    &   1.0754(13)   & & & & \\*
    \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data was originally more like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
        \begin{longtable}[c]{rlll}
        \caption{Data \label{tab:data}} \\
        \toprule
        \( R \)& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{Table \ref{tab:data} continued} \\
        \midrule
        \( R \)& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        
        0.5        & 0.03926622(12)  &   0.6872(5)   &   0.03886(2)   \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   \\
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   \\
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   \\
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   \\
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  \\
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   \\
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   \\
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   \\
        0.5        & 0.03926622(12)  &   0.6872(5)   &   0.03886(2)   \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   \\
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   \\
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   \\
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   \\
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  \\
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   \\
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   \\
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   \\
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   \\
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  \\
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   \\
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   \\
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   \\
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   \\
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  \\
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  \\
        5.0        & 0.03926622(14)  &   0.48923(9)  &   0.027441(3)   \\
                   & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\
                   & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\
                   & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\
                   & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\
                   & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\
                   & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                   & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\
                   & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\
                   & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\
        5.0        & 0.03926622(14)  &   0.48923(9)  &   0.027441(3)   \\
                   & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\
                   & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\
                   & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\
                   & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\
                   & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\
                   & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                   & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\
                   & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\
                   & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\
                   & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\
                   & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\
                   & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                   & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\
                   & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\
                   & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\
                   & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\
                   & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\
                   & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3) \\
    3.0        & 0.0392662(4)    &   0.5040(3)   &   0.028289(9) \\
               & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4676(2)   &   0.05920(2) \\
               & 0.157087(2)     &   0.4000(6)   &   0.13014(7) \\
               & 0.2356338(10)   &   0.3397(2)   &   0.21639(12) \\
               & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2851(3)   &   0.32284(15) \\
               & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2359(6)   &   0.4571(3)  \\
               & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2134(5)   &   0.5380(3)   \\
               & 0.471270(3)     &   0.1919(9)   &   0.6305(4)   \\
               & 0.5105275(14)   &   0.1714(5)   &   0.7372(6)   \\
               & 0.549809(2)     &   0.1519(8)   &   0.8613(8)   \\
               & 0.573261(3)     &   0.141(2)    &   0.9458(10)  \\
               & 0.589086(2)     &   0.1346(7)   &   1.0080(12)  \\
               & 0.604932(4)     &   0.129(2)    &   1.0754(13)  \\
    \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

One can manually break in into three separate tabulars.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}
\begin{table}[p]
    \caption{Data \label{tab:data}}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{rlll}
        \toprule
        \( R \)& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} \\
        \midrule
        0.5        & 0.03926622(12)  &   0.6872(5)   &   0.03886(2)   \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   \\
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   \\
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   \\
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   \\
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  \\
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   \\
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   \\
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   \\
        0.5        & 0.03926622(12)  &   0.6872(5)   &   0.03886(2)   \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   \\
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   \\
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   \\
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   \\
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  \\
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   \\
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   \\
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   \\
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   \\
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  \\
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)  \\
                   & 0.07855013(17)  &   0.6290(2)   &   0.08072(3)   \\
                   & 0.15708670(12)  &   0.5240(2)   &   0.17484(5)   \\
                   & 0.2356338(2)    &   0.43312(11) &   0.28625(6)   \\
                   & 0.31410858(12)  &   0.3549(2)   &   0.42031(7)   \\
                   & 0.39271623(14)  &   0.2875(2)   &   0.58559(11)  \\
                   & 0.43199320(10)  &   0.2572(2)   &   0.68352(12)
    \end{tabular}\hfil
    \begin{tabular}[t]{rlll}
        \toprule
        \( R \)& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} \\
        \midrule
        5.0        & 0.03926622(14)  &   0.48923(9)  &   0.027441(3)   \\
                   & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\
                   & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\
                   & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\
                   & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\
                   & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\
                   & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                   & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\
                   & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\
                   & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\
        5.0        & 0.03926622(14)  &   0.48923(9)  &   0.027441(3)   \\
                   & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\
                   & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\
                   & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\
                   & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\
                   & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\
                   & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                   & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\
                   & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\
                   & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\
                   & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\
                   & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\
                   & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3)  \\
                   & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4551(2)   &   0.057483(8)   \\
                   & 0.157087(2)     &   0.3906(5)   &   0.12666(5)    \\
                   & 0.2356338(11)   &   0.3325(2)   &   0.21097(10)   \\
                   & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2797(2)   &   0.31527(12)   \\
                   & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2319(4)   &   0.4471(2)     \\
                   & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2097(3) 
      \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}[p]
    \centering
    Table \ref{tab:data} continued \\[\abovecaptionskip]
    \begin{tabular}{rlll}
        \toprule
        \( R \)& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(A\)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(B\)} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\(C\)} \\
        \midrule
    3.0        & 0.0392662(4)    &   0.5040(3)   &   0.028289(9) \\
               & 0.0785501(5)    &   0.4676(2)   &   0.05920(2) \\
               & 0.157087(2)     &   0.4000(6)   &   0.13014(7) \\
               & 0.2356338(10)   &   0.3397(2)   &   0.21639(12) \\
               & 0.3141086(12)   &   0.2851(3)   &   0.32284(15) \\
               & 0.392716(2)     &   0.2359(6)   &   0.4571(3)  \\
               & 0.431993(2)     &   0.2134(5)   &   0.5380(3)   \\
               & 0.471270(3)     &   0.1919(9)   &   0.6305(4)   \\
               & 0.5105275(14)   &   0.1714(5)   &   0.7372(6)   \\
               & 0.549809(2)     &   0.1519(8)   &   0.8613(8)   \\
               & 0.573261(3)     &   0.141(2)    &   0.9458(10)  \\
               & 0.589086(2)     &   0.1346(7)   &   1.0080(12)  \\
               & 0.604932(4)     &   0.129(2)    &   1.0754(13)  \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```