# Effect of textcolor is lost across page break occuring in footnote nested in tcolorbox

Tags: color, footnotes, page-breaking, tcolorbox

Here's the minimal example, verified on [David Carlisle's TeXLive.net](https://texlive.net/run):

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtcolorbox{workinprogress}[1][]{
  breakable,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{workinprogress}[oversize]
\lipsum[1-4]
some text\footnote{\textcolor{red}{\lipsum[1-4]}}
\end{workinprogress}

\end{document}
```

As you can see from the screenshot below, the effect of `\textcolor{red}` is lost across a page break.

[image]

Unlike `\textcolor{red}`, however, other commands such as `\emph`, `\textbf`, `\textit`, and `\textsc`, are correctly retained after the page break.

Comment: It could also be a "last page" problem, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601246/longtable-different-last-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

colors in pdflatex are not like fonts. They add a literal and this can get lost at page breaks. Use lualatex and the luacolor package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\newtcolorbox{workinprogress}[1][]{
  breakable,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{workinprogress}[oversize]
\lipsum[1-4] some text\footnote{\textcolor{red}{\lipsum[1-4]}} 
\end{workinprogress}

\end{document}
```

With pdflatex it should be possible too, but it would require additional code to add a color stack, see the pdfcolfoot package.